# Varying number of csv files from Amazon S3 as input to Informatica cloud

Tags: informatica-cloud, iics

I have multiple csv files in Amazon s3 bucket in the same format.But the number of files may change on a daily basis. It maybe 2 in a day and 0 on other days. How can I create an Informatica cloud flow task to read from these varying number of csv files?

Answer (score 0):

Using File Lists in your source is covered in the Informatica documentation [here](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/data-integration/current-version/transformations/transformations/file-lists.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file watcher by implementing event wait task, this would check the files and trigger the workflow if file is present.